# What's wrong with this query using averages?

Tags: mysql, sql

Courses (cid, cname, description)

Professors (pid, pname)

Teaching (tid, cid, pid, year, semester, department)

Students (sid, lname, fname, b_date, department)

Enrolled_stud (sid, tid, enrollment_date, grade, grade_date)

**The Question: query all the students names who have the highest average:**

```
SELECT a.sname,a.avg
FROM (SELECT s1.sname,avg(e.grade)AS avg
      FROM Students s1
      NATURAL JOIN EnrolledStudents e
      GROUP BY s1.sid
      ) as a
where a.avg=(select max(a.avg))
```

you can see the results i get in my [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0e77/44), and you can see that i was doing something wrong, and i dont get what! it all seem correct to me...

Comment: Is this for the free stanford class?

Comment: nope im studying for my DBMS exem...

Comment: what are your expected results? Are you expecting just one row? I guess the problems with the data are not sticking out to me.

Comment: it should output Lilach Dba since she has the highest avg

Comment: bruce, that might work, but i really want to understand whats wrong with the query i came up with... do you have any idea?

Comment: @OfekRon - Are you sure you are not expecting the result to be Jon Gilmour (99.5%)?

Comment: @northpole: He wants all the students with highest grade. Yes, in the sample data it will be just one row, but it may be more in the case of a draw

Comment: @northpole: Jon Gilmour has 90, Lilach Dba has 99.5

Comment: @northpole actually im not sure, the one with the 99.5 is the one i exepct to see...

Comment: all, ya, just realized I had bad results.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's for study, I'll post this hint first. Think about the where clause - `a` is the current row. Of course `a.avg` equals `max(a.avg)`.

**Update**

Try the following:

```
SELECT s1.sname, avg(e.grade) AS avg
FROM Students s1
NATURAL JOIN EnrolledStudents e
GROUP BY s1.sid
HAVING avg = (SELECT avg(e.grade) AS avg 
  FROM EnrolledStudents e
  GROUP BY e.sid ORDER BY avg DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: doesnt it run the max selection first? and uses the result for each a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

Well if no one has a better looking answer that works, then that makes this the best answer:

```
SELECT s.sname
FROM Students s
NATURAL JOIN EnrolledStudents e
GROUP BY s.sid
HAVING avg(e.grade) >= ALL(SELECT AVG(e.grade)
      FROM  EnrolledStudents e
      GROUP BY e.sid)
```

Comment: You do not need to join the `Students` and `EnrolledStudents` tables in the inner query.